# Vuepress inserting � between every character in my markdown file?

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vuepress

Here is what the index.html file is built to in the dist folder when running `npm vuepress build`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Documentation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Writing Serious Documentation For Serious Things">
    
    <link rel="preload" href="/assets/css/1.styles.cf04a93f.css" as="style"><link rel="preload" href="/assets/js/app.a3bdb5c0.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/assets/js/0.5e0e2db4.js" as="script">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/1.styles.cf04a93f.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" data-server-rendered="true"><div class="theme-container no-sidebar"><header class="navbar"><div class="sidebar-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="icon"><path fill="currentColor" d="M436 124H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12V80c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm0 160H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-32c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12zm0 160H12c-6.627 0-12-5.373-12-12v-32c0-6.627 5.373-12 12-12h424c6.627 0 12 5.373 12 12v32c0 6.627-5.373 12-12 12z"></path></svg></div><a href="/" class="router-link-exact-active router-link-active"><!----><span class="site-name">
      Documentation
    </span></a><div class="links"><div class="search-box"><input aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" value=""><!----></div><!----></div></header><div class="sidebar"><!----><ul class="sidebar-links"><li><a href="/" class="active sidebar-link">/</a></li></ul></div><div class="page"><div class="content"><p>��-�-�-�
�
�h�o�m�e�:� �t�r�u�e�
�
�h�e�r�o�I�m�a�g�e�:� �/�h�e�r�o�.�p�n�g�
�
�a�c�t�i�o�n�T�e�x�t�:� �G�e�t� �S�t�a�r�t�e�d� ��!
�
�a�c�t�i�o�n�L�i�n�k�:� �/�g�u�i�d�e�/�
�
�f�e�a�t�u�r�e�s�:�
�
�-� �t�i�t�l�e�:� �S�i�m�p�l�i�c�i�t�y� �F�i�r�s�t�
�
� � �d�e�t�a�i�l�s�:� �M�i�n�i�m�a�l� �s�e�t�u�p� �w�i�t�h� �m�a�r�k�d�o�w�n�-�c�e�n�t�e�r�e�d� �p�r�o�j�e�c�t� �s�t�r�u�c�t�u�r�e� �h�e�l�p�s� �y�o�u� �f�o�c�u�s� �o�n� �w�r�i�t�i�n�g�.�
�
�-� �t�i�t�l�e�:� �V�u�e�-�P�o�w�e�r�e�d�
�
� � �d�e�t�a�i�l�s�:� �E�n�j�o�y� �t�h�e� �d�e�v� �e�x�p�e�r�i�e�n�c�e� �o�f� �V�u�e� �+� �w�e�b�p�a�c�k�,� �u�s�e� �V�u�e� �c�o�m�p�o�n�e�n�t�s� �i�n� �m�a�r�k�d�o�w�n�,� �a�n�d� �d�e�v�e�l�o�p� �c�u�s�t�o�m� �t�h�e�m�e�s� �w�i�t�h� �V�u�e�.�
�
�-� �t�i�t�l�e�:� �P�e�r�f�o�r�m�a�n�t�
�
� � �d�e�t�a�i�l�s�:� �V�u�e�P�r�e�s�s� �g�e�n�e�r�a�t�e�s� �p�r�e�-�r�e�n�d�e�r�e�d� �s�t�a�t�i�c� �H�T�M�L� �f�o�r� �e�a�c�h� �p�a�g�e�,� �a�n�d� �r�u�n�s� �a�s� �a�n� �S�P�A� �o�n�c�e� �a� �p�a�g�e� �i�s� �l�o�a�d�e�d�.�
�
�f�o�o�t�e�r�:� �M�I�T� �L�i�c�e�n�s�e�d� �|� �C�o�p�y�r�i�g�h�t� ��� �2�0�1�8�-�p�r�e�s�e�n�t� �E�v�a�n� �Y�o�u�
�
�-�-�-�
�
�#� �H�e�l�l�o� �V�u�e�P�r�e�s�s�
�
�
�
�s�k�d�f�n�j�k�d�h�f� �l�a�s�j�d�h�f�l�k�a�j�s�d�h�f�l�a�k�j�s�d�h� �f�l�k�d�j�s�h�f� � �d�f�j�k�l�a�s� �d�f�l�j�a� �s�d�f�l�h�a�s� �j�d�f�</p></div><!----><!----></div></div></div>
    <script src="/assets/js/0.5e0e2db4.js" defer></script><script src="/assets/js/app.a3bdb5c0.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I followed the documentation to the letter and cannot figure out why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a friendly comment for anyone ending up here with Vuepress markdown rendering problems (or build problems): formatting anything inside your markdown file with a left arrow (`<`) that doesn't have a matching closing right arrow (`>`) can break the Vuepress build. Comb through your markdown file(s) and ensure you haven't accidentally left out a closing right arrow/greater than symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My markdown file was incorrectly encoded. Switching to UTF-8 and rerunning the dev and build scripts worked like a charm.  Thanks to [EmileBergeron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218980/emile-bergeron).

Comment: please provide the detailed solution